# Regex to extract first occurance of matching field

Tags: regex

I want to extract first occurance of matching field. there are multiple occurrence present in same line.I have created a regex but its capturing the second occurence.

[My Regex:Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lL9FIx/1)
.

**Sample Data:**
127776.635: [Full GC127776.636: [CMS: **12058623**K->11149597K(12058624K), 28.5725635 secs] **12355879**K->11149597K(12478080K), [CMS Perm : 75918K->75548K(262144K)], 28.5729197 secs] [Times: user=28.58 sys=0.01, real=28.57 secs]

In above example it should take 12058623K, not 12355879K.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to match closing `]` here just use this regex with lazy quantifier:

```
\[Full GC.*?\s(?P<before_full_gc>\d+)K
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lL9FIx/2)